# How to insert text into popup using Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a button on clicking on it it is opening a Popup. The Popup contains below fields like., Textbox, OK and Cancel buttons. I am fine with cancel and Ok buttons. Help me in Giving text to that textbox using Robot Frame work. I am not able to find the Id/Name/Xpath of that particular field.

Comment: Update the code you tried with

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the popup is a proper window and not an alert, you just need to select the window after it pops up.  After that, your usual keywords like `Input Text` will work as expected.

The [selenium2library user guide](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window) explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Input text is the way to go about this but what the locator is depends on how you are creating this pop-up. Please show us the code you are using to create the pop-up and then we can help you to add a locator to it. Generaly I use jquery locators as they are incredibly powerful so I would recommend looking to that as a way forward.